# Is there a problem with saying "for Pete's sake"?

Tags: halacha, names, avodah-zarah, christianity

Is there a halachic issue with invoking the name "Peter," or, as is more commonly used, "oh, for Pete's sake!," which I assume is a reference to [Saint Peter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Peter). Wikipedia [agrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Peter#Popular_culture) with this conjecture, albeit without a source; see also ["Oh, for Pete's sake!"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/11785/74434) on English.SE

As far as I know, nobody treats Peter as a deity, but he is a saint. Is there an issue with saying "oh, for Pete's sake!," due to his being a saint?

Comment: +1, i've wondered this myself. Just never within range of MY. :)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50658/5323, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22836/5323

Comment: @Scimonster I had to think of *something* to [ask on the app today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246007/how-do-hats-modify-users-behavior/246136#comment805658_246008), that [didn't require heavy linking, or script use](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246019/266359) ;-)

Comment: ...well, curiosity got the better of me, since I was also wondering about the phrase's origin..Google said it was a "substitution phrase" so folks wouldn't use the name of our fellow Jew whose birthday is today-or Jan 7th..and a movie..and a line of jewelry....and a deli, etc..."for goodness' sake" seemed to be the next phase of its evolution..just an exclamatory phrase that's been through several phases in its long life....

Comment: Some interesting posts about this: [Is there a secular, non vulgar alternative to "for heaven's sake"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/155717) | ["Oh, for Pete's sake!"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11785)

Comment: @fredsbend Thanks for those links; they look interesting!

Comment: Assuming the halachik definition of a deity with regards to idolatry is a being with superpowers that is prayed to, I think saints by definition qualify since I believe the Catholic church canonizes saints by declaring that they performed miracles post-mortem in response to prayer. (If we assume a different definition, I'm not sure what it is that would still be including old pagan deities.)

Comment: Rivevos Ephraim in chelek 8 was asked if one can mention citys and street names like church avenue , saint ... street and so on.

Comment: @sam The largest Jewish community in New Zealand is in Christchurch.  Awkward.

Comment: @ShaulBehr - I wonder if the super-Charedim pronounce that town at BlankBlank. :)

Comment: Rav  Tam believed Peter to be a devout and learned Jew and attributed the Nishmat prayer to him.

Answer (score 7):

Referring to the names of men or women made deities is not problematic. See Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Dei'ah 147:2.
The problem is that Beis Yoseif there quotes Rabeinu Yerucham (TAvC 17:5 [159c]) who understands from Avi HaEzri that one may mention the names of Christian so-called 'saints' themselves but may not mention them with any language of honor. This would preclude the title of 'Saint' before the names of these individuals. Exclamations like 'For Pete's sake!' are technically referred to as oaths in language, for all such exclamations are meant to invoke Heaven, Hell, or deity. Hence, I would consider it inadvisable to use such an expression for the usage itself conveys an implied reverence which is inappropriate.