# Does Shemot 23:13 literally mean Marvel & DC Comics are forbidden?

Tags: halacha, names, avodah-zarah, speech-talking, mishpatim

Does **Shemot 23:13** literally mean Marvel & DC Comics are forbidden?

"and **the name of the gods of others you shall not mention**; it shall not be heard through your mouth." ( וְשֵׁ֨ם אֱלֹהִ֤ים אֲחֵרִים֙ לֹ֣א תַזְכִּ֔ירוּ לֹ֥א יִשָּׁמַ֖ע עַל־פִּֽיךָ )

- Does this apply to discussing fictional movies / reading fictional books about ancient deities from Norse & Greek mythology which are celebrated in pop culture?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28057/759

Comment: Related (ever so slightly): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50658/16354

Comment: Related (and the more I think about it, possibly a duplicate?): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37767/reading-books-about-avodah-zarah

Comment: I heard once (can't remember where), that depictions in modern fiction of mythological figures aren't comparable to the issurim in halacha because most such depictions show these gods as deeply flawed, sometimes even outright mocking them.

Comment: Unless you worship the characters or celebrities playing them, it does not constitute as idolatry. Come on man. You know these are made-up movies, don't you?