# saying the word "Jesus"

Tags: halacha, names, avodah-zarah, christianity

The standard practice seems to be avoiding saying the word "Jesus" due to the halacha of שם רשעים ירקב, but some people seem to be willing to say it. Is there a heter for this? (Also, would this heter apply to "Buddha", "Krishna", etc.?)

Comment: Duplicate of first question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22836 . Related to the question in parentheses: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17301

Comment: Is that really standard practice in all communities?

Comment: @DoubleAA Not sure. I was only basing it off of my own experiences.