# Name of avoda zara in the mishna?

Tags: avodah-zarah, mishna, maseches-sanhedrin, masecheth-avodah-zarah

[Avoda Zara 3, 4](//www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Avodah_Zarah.3.4):

> שאל פרוקלוס... שהיה רוחץ במרחץ של אפרודיטי
>   Proclus asked... because he was washing in the bathroom of aphroditi ...

Given it is forbidden to say name of avoda zara ([Sanhedrin 63b](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3736&size=1)):

> שלא יאמר אדם לחבירו שמור לי בצד עבודה זרה פלונית
>   ...[we learn from this verse] that a man won't say to his friend "wait me near avoda zara X"...

how could this name be cited in the mishna?

Comment: http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0425.htm#3 ?

Comment: http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0320.htm#2 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [May one use the name of an avodah zara?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17301/may-one-use-the-name-of-an-avodah-zara)

Comment: @DonielF Not a dupe: problem there is about using the name for *another* use; but here, the bathroom was (at first thought) named after the avoda zara itself. However, interesting pointer, thank you.

Comment: @Kazibácsi Not a problem: the Talmud in Sanhedrin says that names mentioned in the TN"Ch are permitted.

Comment: Check the cited answer of @DonielF